# How can I assign a new value to a class variable (numpy array) using another thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, numpy, thread-safety

Consider the following code where I replace the value of a class variable (a numpy array). Why isn't the value of m.mydict changed?

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import numpy as np

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):

        #self.var = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        self.mydict = {'a1': None,
                        'a2': None}
        self.lock = Lock()

    def mythread(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.lock.acquire()
        b = np.array([9,9,9])
        arg2 = b
        self.lock.release()

    def test(self, condition):
        if condition:
            Thread(target=self.mythread, args=(0, self.mydict['a1'])).start()
        else:
            Thread(target=self.mythread, args=(0, self.mydict['a2'])).start()
        

m = MyClass()
m.test(True)

print(m.mydict)

>>> {'a1': None, 'a2': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no sense to pass `self.var` (or other instance attribute) by reference when your thread has a direct access to the instance `self`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...

    def mythread(self, arg1):
        b = np.array([9, 9, 9, 9, 9])
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.var = b
        self.lock.release()

    def test(self):
        Thread(target=self.mythread, args=(0,)).start()

m = MyClass()
m.test()
print(m.var)
```

---

```
[9 9 9 9 9]
```

---

The same with your 2nd version which is poorly designed. Here's how it can be fixed:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # self.var = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        self.mydict = {'a1': None, 'a2': None}
        self.lock = Lock()

    def mythread(self, arg1, key):
        self.lock.acquire()
        b = np.array([9, 9, 9])
        self.mydict[key] = b
        self.lock.release()

    def test(self, condition):
        if condition:
            Thread(target=self.mythread, args=(0, 'a1')).start()
        else:
            Thread(target=self.mythread, args=(0, 'a2')).start()


m = MyClass()
m.test(True)

print(m.mydict)
```

---

```
{'a1': array([9, 9, 9]), 'a2': None}
```

Comment: In the real case, I can pass different variables to mythread so I cannot directly access it

Comment: @firion, so construct your question/description properly to avoid confusion. Your current thread definitely has access to `self`

Comment: done. The condition is determined during the execution

Comment: @firion, Again, you are making a bad design while still having access to `self`. See my update

Comment: Ok, thanks. By the way, I was also interested in why does this happen, regardless of the design choices